# Get row with closest date in other dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes
Dataframe1:

```
id date1
1 11-04-2022
1 03-02-2011
2 03-05-2222
3 01-01-2001
4 02-02-2012
```

and Dataframe2:

```
id date2 data data2
1 11-02-2222 1 3
1 11-02-1999 3 4
1 11-03-2022 4 5
2 22-03-4444 5 6
2 22-02-2020 7 8
...
```

What I would like to do is take the row  from dataframe2 with the closest date to date1 in Dataframe1 but it has to fit the id, but the date has to be before the one of date1
The desired output would look like this:

```
id date1 date2 data data2
1 11-04-2022 11-03-2022 4 5
1 03-02-2011 11-02-1999 3 4
2 03-05-2222 22-02-2020 7 8
```

How would I do this using pandas?

Answer (score 5):

Try [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas-merge-asof), but first convert date1, date2 to datetime and sort both timeframes:

```py
df1["date1"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["date1"])
df2["date2"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["date2"])

df1 = df1.sort_values(by="date1")
df2 = df2.sort_values(by="date2")

print(
    pd.merge_asof(
        df1,
        df2,
        by="id",
        left_on="date1",
        right_on="date2",
        direction="nearest",
    ).dropna(subset=["date2"])
)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but how would I make it so that it will select the things which have a date2 which is the closest to date1, but date2<date1

Comment: @jr123456jr987654321 Try to change the `direction=` parameter (to "backward" or "forward" - as you want.)