# Get row with closest date in other dataframe pandas, but the date has to be before the one in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68004827/get-row-with-closest-date-in-other-dataframe-pandas) question, however I did not take into account another problem. Date2 has to be before Date1. Due to me having thought that the expected output would have made it a bit more obvious. Here is the question:
I have 2 dataframes
Dataframe1:

```
id date1
1 11-04-2022
1 03-02-2011
2 03-05-2222
3 01-01-2001
4 02-02-2012
```

and Dataframe2:

```
id date2 data data2
1 11-02-2222 1 3
1 11-02-1999 3 4
1 11-03-2022 4 5
2 22-03-4444 5 6
2 22-02-2020 7 8
...
```

What I would like to do is take the row  from dataframe2 with the closest date to date1 in Dataframe1 but it has to fit the id, but the date has to be before the one of date1
The desired output would look like this:

```
id date1 date2 data data2
1 11-04-2022 11-03-2022 4 5
1 03-02-2011 11-02-1999 3 4
2 03-05-2222 22-02-2020 7 8
...
```

How would I do this using pandas?

So how would I do that without resorting the df1?

Answer (score 0):

There is necessary change `4444` year for possible convert to datetimes and then for me working default `direction ='backward'` (should be omitted):

```
df1["date1"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["date1"])
df2["date2"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["date2"])

df1 = df1.sort_values(by="date1")
df2 = df2.sort_values(by="date2")


print(
    pd.merge_asof(
        df1,
        df2,
        by="id",
        left_on="date1",
        right_on="date2",
    ).dropna(subset=["date2"])
)
   id      date1      date2  data  data2
1   1 2011-03-02 1999-11-02   3.0    4.0
3   1 2022-11-04 2022-11-03   4.0    5.0
4   2 2222-03-05 2020-02-22   7.0    8.0
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you but can you check my answer if you have time. I don't understand the error of the OP. ty

Comment: @Corralien - Hard to know, maybe small RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Input data:

```
>>> df1
   id      date1
0   1 2022-11-04
1   1 2011-03-02
2   2 2222-03-05
3   3 2001-01-01
4   4 2012-02-02

>>> df2
   id      date2  data  data2
0   1 2222-11-02     1      3
1   1 1999-11-02     3      4
2   1 2022-11-03     4      5
3   2 2222-03-22     5      6  # 4444 -> 2222
4   2 2020-02-22     7      8
```

Alternative to `merge_asof` without before sorting: merge the two dataframes, compute difference between `date1` and `date2` and find the nearest dates only if `date1 >= date2`.

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id')
df['delta'] = df['date1'] - df['date2']  # compute difference betwee
mask = df['delta'] >= pd.Timedelta(0)  # only if date1 >= date2
out = df.loc[df[mask].groupby(['id', 'date1'])['delta'].idxmin()]
```

Output result:

```
>>> out
   id      date1      date2  data  data2      delta
4   1 2011-03-02 1999-11-02     3      4  4138 days
2   1 2022-11-04 2022-11-03     4      5     1 days
7   2 2222-03-05 2020-02-22     7      8 73790 days
```

Comment: you cannot merge df1 and df2 due to them having a different number of rows

Comment: I don't understand. Why you cannot merge 2 dataframe with a different number of rows. Do you have an error message?

Comment: yeah I do get an error message, it runs exponentially

Comment: After some time I get a run time error, btw Im dealing with 500,000 different examples (for each dataframe)