# Reducing amount of data lost from merging 2 dataframes together pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have asked this question:
I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68004827/get-row-with-closest-date-in-other-dataframe-pandas) question, however I did not take into account another problem. Date2 has to be before Date1. Due to me having thought that the expected output would have made it a bit more obvious. Here is the question:
I have 2 dataframes
Dataframe1:

```
id date1
1 11-04-2022
1 03-02-2011
2 03-05-2222
3 01-01-2001
4 02-02-2012
```

and Dataframe2:

```
id date2 data data2
1 11-02-2222 1 3
1 11-02-1999 3 4
1 11-03-2022 4 5
2 22-03-4444 5 6
2 22-02-2020 7 8
...
```

What I would like to do is take the row  from dataframe2 with the closest date to date1 in Dataframe1 but it has to fit the id, but the date has to be before the one of date1
The desired output would look like this:

```
id date1 date2 data data2
1 11-04-2022 11-03-2022 4 5
1 03-02-2011 11-02-1999 3 4
2 03-05-2222 22-02-2020 7 8
...
```

How would I do this using pandas?

So how would I do that without resorting the df1?

and the answer to it was this:

```
df1["date1"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["date1"])
df2["date2"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["date2"])

df1 = df1.sort_values(by="date1")
df2 = df2.sort_values(by="date2")


print(
    pd.merge_asof(
        df1,
        df2,
        by="id",
        left_on="date1",
        right_on="date2",
    ).dropna(subset=["date2"])
)
```

When I ran this, there where allot of NaN's produced (even-though there was no reason), resulting in me loosing 60% of my data. How would I edit that approach in order to reduce the amount of NaNs produced and so dropped, so that I do not loose extraordinary amounts of data?

Comment: try adding `direction=forward`

Answer (score 1):

You should try to play with the parameter 'direction' from pandas merge_asof.
Then, I don't know if it can help you in this case, but you can also use the 'thresh' parameter from dropna().